# Define variable in JBOSS application server level

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I searched for way to define variable in **`JBOSS`** application and use it in my web application, but  I did not find any tutorial,

so I want to ask, can I define variable in the JBOSS server level?

and use it in multiple application deployed in server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the server-wide system properties.

For example, to define the system properties in `standalone.xml`, add them right after the `extensions` section:

```
<system-properties>
     <property name="my.property.first" value="Some value 1"/>
     <property name="my.property.second" value="Some value 2"/>
</system-properties>
```

Then you can use the properties in any deployed application, for example:

```
System.getProperty("my.property.first") // Returns "Some value 1"
```

Comment: what is the solution in cluster mode?

Comment: For standalone cluster instances repeat the configuration in each `standalone.xml`. For domain mode add the properties in `domain.xml`. More information can be found [here](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SystemProperties).

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of approaches one could take, one of them being creating a custom module and each project that needs access to your variables (properties) will depend on that module. See this reference https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath

Hope that helps